# Type Parameter of Sub-Interface has "inconsistent values"

Tags: oop, kotlin, interface, jvm

So i have objects that can be compared in different ways. I have a class hierarchy where the base objects must define how to be compared in every possible way whereas there is a standard way for some of the sub-classes to be compared so these methods can be given defaults.

This is hard to explain in words, so here is some code

```
// This is akin to how `Comparable<in T>` is defined
interface AllComparisons<in T> {
    // this interface has all the possible comparison methods
    fun cmp1(other: T): Int
    fun cmp2(other: T): Int
}

interface SomeComparisons<in T>: AllComparisons<T> {
    // this interface has a default for some comparison methods
    override fun cmp2(other: T) = -this.cmp1(other)  // eg
}


// This is akin to how a comparable object `Obj: Comparable<Obj>` is defined
abstract class BaseClass: AllComparisons<BaseClass>  // must define both cmp1 and cmp2

abstract class SubClass: BaseClass(), SomeComparisons<SubClass>  // only must define cmp1
```

This throws a compiler error on the final line:

```
Type parameter T of 'AllComparisons' has inconsistent values: BaseClass, SubClass
```

My Questions are:

1. Why is this disallowed? Is this a compiler limitation or is there actually a logical inconsistency?
2. What can I do to fix it? I'd prefer to not move the defaulting logic (for `cmp2`) from `SomeComparisons` into `SubClass` because it's not the only time I need to use this pattern and it would result in a lot of re-used code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember about type erasure. The methods in `AllComparisons` and `SomeComparisons` are actually

```
fun cmp1(other: Object): Int
fun cmp2(other: Object): Int
```

and when you implement

```
override fun cmp2(other: BaseClass)
```

in `BaseClass`, you also get compiler-generated

```
override fun cmp2(other: Object) = cmp2(other as BaseClass)
```

And `SubClass` inherits that implementation, but to implement `SomeComparisons<SubClass>` it *also* needs

```
override fun cmp2(other: Object) = cmp2(other as SubClass)
```

And of course you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So it is completely unavoidable then with my current implementation?

Comment: Yes, so far as I know. In Java it certainly is (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5), and Kotlin probably doesn't make any changes here.